# Unable to activate Trezor Suite

Tags: software-installation

Trezor Suite 23.9.3.3 linux--86_64.Appl downloaded from Trezor website, but cannot open it. The icon is in Apps file, but no response when clicked on.

Comment: You've provided no clues as to what OS/release & architecture you're using, is your machine compatible  (*we won't know as you provided no specifics*)